# How can I setup Bluetooth on 16.04 LTS

Tags: drivers, 16.04, bluetooth

when I open Bluetooth from system setting I found that it is available to change the stat of bluetooth but unavailable to change visibility and even I open Bluetooth but also it doesn't work
laptop model : probook 450 G1

out put of  lspci -knn | grep Net -A2; lsusb :

```
04:00.0 Network controller [0280]: MEDIATEK Corp. MT7630e 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter [14c3:7630]
    DeviceName: WLAN
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company MT7630e 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter [103c:197c]
    Kernel driver in use: mt7630e
    Kernel modules: mt7630e
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8008 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 04f2:b3c8 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 003 Device 006: ID 0e8d:763f MediaTek Inc. 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2; lsusb` terminal command.

Comment: I do not think that this BT device is supported by Linux.

Comment: See [this article](https://neurobin.org/projects/softwares/unix/MT7630E/)

Comment: This can be fixed by a custom kernel module.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't know Custom kernel module ?

Comment: The best way is to report this issue to Launchpad. Probably someone will send a patch upstream or build a module.